# c++ auto type signed to/from unsigned conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to write a function that performs bit-wise operations on a parameter that is `auto` type.

- The type passed in might be `unsigned int` or `int` type (with differing widths).
- I only want to perform bit-wise operations on `unsigned` types.

I need an operator that returns the `unsigned` version of the original data type. In the function example below the "operator" `unsigned_type` would give me the data type that `value` has but insure it is unsigned.

- `int` -> `unsigned int`
- `int16_t` -> `uint16_t`
- `uint16_t` -> `uint16_t`

Function example:

```
auto bit_shifting_and_mask(auto value) -> decltype(value)
{
    unsigned_type(value) unsigned_value = static_cast<unsigned_type(value)>(value);

    unsigned_value >>= 8u;       // Contrived bit manipulation
    unsigned_value &= 0xABCDu;   // here ...

    return static_cast<decltype(value)>(unsigned_value);
}
```

Is there some means to perform the operation `unsigned_type` against a data type obtained from `decltype`?

Thanks.

Comment: [make_unsigned](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned).

Comment: Argh! Please also enumerate all of the other obvious things I have yet to learn from C++1x. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 has a [`std::make_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned) utility in `<type_traits>`:

```
auto bit_shifting_and_mask(auto value) -> decltype(value)
{
    auto unsigned_value = static_cast<std::make_unsigned<decltype(value)>::type>(value);

    unsigned_value >>= 8u;       // Contrived bit manipulation
    unsigned_value &= 0xABCDu;   // here ...

    return static_cast<decltype(value)>(unsigned_value);
}
```

With C++14, you can simplify further by using `std::make_unsigned_t` instead of `std::make_unsigned::type`.

Comment: Are auto parameters something new that VC++17 does not support yet?

Comment: @JiveDadson It's still a TS feature. Not in the latest standard yet. Maybe it'll be in the next one.

Answer (score 2):

[make_unsigned](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned), as Jarod42 said.

```
auto bit_shifting_and_mask(auto value) -> decltype(value)
```

This is not the way you want to make this function type-dependent. Use template, unless this function is lambda.

Comment: AFAIK, this already is `template<typename T> T bit_shifting_and_mask(T value)`, but with modern spelling.

Comment: This feature AFAIK is still not implemented in C++17 standard. I accept it though as a shortcut to visualize the problem.

Comment: It must be implemented in OP's compiler, or they wouldn't be able to use it.

Comment: I've just checked: it works on GCC.
However other compilers also would not produce errors. It would just not work the way he thinks it would. Other compilers deduce types once.

Comment: Thanks for that warning - I was not aware this was GCC specific.

Comment: @razzorflame Have you found one that doesn't produce errors? Prior to this (suggested) feature, `auto` was not allowed on a function parameter. (And gcc also deduces types once.)

Comment: GCC 8.0.1 from www.wandbox.org with C++17 mode. I also tried on ideone which has only C++14 support and it deduced it for every instatiation, like it was template. www.ideone.com/Xe6ixa

Answer (score 2):

This does not require features not (yet) in the standard. It compiles under VS 2017 with VC++17 enabled.

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T>
auto bit_shifting_and_mask(T value) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>, 
        "bit_shifting_and_mask(value): value is not integral type");
    using unsgn =std::make_unsigned_t<T>;
    auto unsigned_value = static_cast<unsgn>(value);

    unsigned_value >>= 8u;       // Contrived bit manipulation
    unsigned_value &= 0xABCDu;   // here ...

    return unsigned_value;
}
```

Comment: Yea! Nine grand rep points. I'm gonna get that toaster oven for sure.